# How to Display different Components on selection options from Dropdown menu using React js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dropdown-tree-select

I am new to React js, Any help will be appreciated.
What I want is to display different Components with different texts on the selection of different options in Dropdown Menu.

I am able to display value using {this.state.value} but this is not what I want.
Here is the link to my existing code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-noyce-cj466

Comment: what are the components you want to display can you give any examples

Comment: I have updated my code. Suppose if you click on python a component name python should display text with python, same with android should display component named android should display text with android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi and welcome to SO =)

If you want to render different component relying on some condition then you can make something like this:

```
{item === "first" && <Component1 />}
{item === "second" && <Component2 />}
{item === "third" && <Component3 />}
```

You can find more information about conditional rendering here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

And here is a great article about reconciliation by Dan Abramov: https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/#reconciliation

Comment: Thank you @Ivan for your answer. It solved my doubt.

Comment: I'm glad to help =)

Comment: "So the better (performant) way is to use ternary operator"  are you sure it's true?

Comment: @DennisVash, you are actually right! React places the `null` under the hood in such constructions `{item === "first" && <Component1 />}`. I edit my answer, thanks!

Comment: Feel free to upvote https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961689/rendering-a-component-with-logical-vs-ternary-operator/57962054#57962054

Answer (score 4):

Others have already pointed out how to dynamically render components if you only have a few, but if you have a lot of them you might want to store them in a dictionary:

```
const Android = () => (
  <span>android</span>
);

const Python = () => (
  <span>python</span>
);

const components = {
  "android": Android,
  "python": Python,
};

const Main = () => {
  // choose here based on a key
  const Component = components['android'];
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component/>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways to display different components based on a variable or state is to use inline conditional rendering.  You can try something like:

```
{this.state.value === "test" ? <Component1 />: <Component2 />}
```

You can also pass `this.state.value` as a property to another component which renders other elements (or components) conditionally. You should really go through some of the basic react tutorials if you're new as this is part of them - [see examples](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: what about If I have more than 2 components

Comment: Did you open the link I gave you on the answer? There's also an example with  if-else. You can use if(test1) {res = <Comp1 />} else if(test2) {res = <Comp2 />} else if(test3) {res = <Comp3 />} ... or even a switch if you'd like.